# let $\Theta:\mathbb Z/n\to\mathbb C^*$ be a homomorphism .Show that $Im(\Theta)\subset\mu_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory

let $\Theta:\mathbb Z/n\to\mathbb C^*$ be a homomorphism then we have to show that $\mathrm{Im}(\Theta)\subset\mu_n$.

My try: $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb C^*:r\mapsto \left(1\mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi i r}{n}}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be in $\mathbb Z$, we denote by $\pi_n$ the projection onto $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$.

You have since $\Theta$ is an homomorphism:

$$\Theta(\pi_b (k))^n=\theta(\pi_n(kn))=\Theta(\pi_n (0))=1.$$

So

$$\mathrm{Im}(\Theta)\subset \mu_n.$$

Comment: We denote by ?(in your 1st line)

Comment: @MatheMagic I wrote $\overline .$, but I'll change the notation since it might not be very easy to read.

Comment: @MatheMagic I used that where I say that $\pi_n(kn)=\pi_n(0)$, which is just $kn\equiv 0\pmod n$.